# Screen Reader NVDA 2015.2 reads the heading of AngularUI's datepicker twice

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, angular-ui, nvda, angular-ui-datepicker

So I'm using an angular UI Datepicker: [**link to gitgub**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with [**NVDA**](http://www.nvaccess.org/) screen reader (latest version).

The problem is related with table heading live region: when switching to another set of data (years, months, days), the heading is being read twice sometimes:
[image]

Here is an HTML structure:

```
<button id="*" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button"  ng-click="toggleMode()">
     <strong class="ng-binding">September 2015</strong>
</button>
```

Same ARIA roles are being used in [**this**](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/15/) example of accessible datepicker. However, in the example above the heading is read only once.

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example to run with your datepicker?  Does this only happen with NVDA?  VoiceOver and JAWS are ok?

Comment: @slugolicious The datepciker was tested both on my site and here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (scroll to datepicker) – same result. Didn't test with other screenreaders yet.